# Fetching external website meta tags vs fb debugger

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to retrieve meta tags of an external website.

In the view source, I can't see these tags and the only way to get them is by inspecting the elements. However, if I debug the url with facebook debugger, all meta tags are there just fine.

I'm struggled into finding a way to get those tags as a php variables.

The URL: https://play.anghami.com/song/45345900
How FB Scraper sees it: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.anghami.com%2Fsong%2F45345900

Comment: You want to get <meta name="description"> metatitle?

Comment: The page might simply return different content based on the requesting User-Agent, so try to make your request send the same one Facebook does. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1748179212062572

Comment: I want to get some meta tags similar to what Facebook scraper is getting: 
<meta property="og:title" content="Good Luck, Ugly! - Glue-Soaked Heart | Play for free on Anghami">
<meta property="og:description" content='Play "Glue-Soaked Heart" by "Good Luck, Ugly!" (Glue-Soaked Heart، Good Luck, Ugly!) '>

Comment: I tried to change User-Agent but that didn't help:

header('User-Agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1');
$html = file_get_contents('http://play.anghami.com/song/45345900');
echo show_source($html);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, this code pulls entire webpage, but you can optimize it the way you like.

```
 $ch = curl_init(); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: text/plain'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://play.anghami.com/song/45345900'); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
 $output = curl_exec($ch); 
 curl_close($ch);  
 header('Content-Type: text/plain');
 echo $output;
 exit;
```

Comment: In the view source, I can't see these tags and the only way to get them is by inspecting the elements. Your code is getting the source code which has no meta data.

Comment: I want to get exactly what is shown here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.anghami.com%2Fsong%2F45345900

Comment: @TonyAS i printed values of $_SERVER and trying to add it using curl, lets see or we can try exec

Comment: Thanks I much appreciate your efforts. Let me know if you figure it out.

Comment: Did you have any success?

Comment: @TonyAS No, I tried but no luck. Let me check again with some new CURL setopt's....